# Is it weird idea to use youtube instead of firebase storage service for my app's video cloud storage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, youtube

I'm now using Spark Plan of Firebase which is totally free. And recently getting my app involved with videos, I found that bandwidth is getting too high near my free plan's limitation, which means I need to pay for larger plan when i release my app to market. Then this idea popped up. I know that paying for cloud storage is normal and good idea for the service, but using youtube and embedding that youtube link into app ui doesn't sound impossible. Then it would be free..! Additionally, i found weird official presentation by Google: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2OG1w6bGFo&feature=youtu.be&t=2060

How do you think of using youtube as free cloud storage for our app? Is it just weird and semi-wrong idea?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very efficient storage and bandwidth wise, and it’s possible there might be a number of issues with the video quality messing up the data. It’s also possible that Youtube will flag you for unusual upload patterns.

Comment: Yup I thought same but the video linked changed my idea. The official said that it is not impossible. The speech was interesting!